# Disable only one Gutenberg block programatically / coblock/maps not listed in blocks

Tags: block-editor

I have installed https://github.com/godaddy-wordpress/coblocks and want to provide only OpenStreetMap based blocks (which I installed additionally) and remove the `coblocks/map` block.

```
add_filter( 'allowed_block_types_all', 'myplugin_allowed_block_types', 0 );

function myplugin_allowed_block_types( $allowed_blocks )
{
    $block_types = WP_Block_Type_Registry::get_instance()->get_all_registered();
    if (!isset($block_types['coblocks/map'])) {
        wp_die('Block not found to unset');
    }
    unset($block_types['coblocks/map']);
    return array_keys($block_types);
}
```

This dies with `Block not found to unset`

Actually the code works without that check, but I am wondering if there are other blocks which are not in the registry but still work and would be disabled with my code.

So essentially I am asking why `get_all_registered` does not have some blocks which are still there and how I can remove only specific blocks if I can not reliably fetch a list of all blocks.

Comment: Doing this via PHP isn't the most reliable due to the poor API design of that filter. You're better off using a filter in JS to modify the block so that `inserter` is set to `false` in its supports section

Comment: you'll also want to avoid `wp_die`, this might kill other block based areas or post types e.g. the widget block areas

Comment: Thanks, the wp_die was for illustration :) how do create a JS filter? Feel free to post as answer

Comment: I don't have code to share, but hooks in the editor are well documented in the official handbook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to target the block specifically via javascript. Brief example:

```
wp.domReady(function() {
    wp.blocks.unregisterBlockType( 'coblocks/map' );
});
```

Save that to a js file and enqueue it via your custom function: `add_action('enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'your_custom_enqueue_fucntion')`